# VBScript and batch file fails when run by Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, wsh, windows-scripting

I have a VBScript that checks to see if MS Word is running hidden, makes it visible, then hides it again.

here is the script code that works fine when I double click the file in Explorer:

```
dim oWord
Dim wshShell, btn
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

set oWord = getobject(, "Word.Application")

if isobject(oWord) then 
    on error goto 0
    wshShell.Popup "Word is running, making visible", 7, "ALPS Push print", &H0 + &H40
    oWord.visible=true
    wshShell.Popup "MS Word is now visible" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Waiting 30 seconds then hiding it", 30, "ALPS Push print", &H0 + &H30
    oWord.visible=false
else    
    wshShell.Popup "Word is not running" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Quitting", 7, "ALPS Push print", &H0 + &H40
end if
```

It works find when I run it, but when it runs under Task Scheduler it fails so I created a batch file to launch it

```
wscript C:\dev\checkALPS.vbs
```

Now when I try to run it from the Task Scheduler, it still fails with the below error message

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: C:\dev\checkALPS.bat
Line:   7
Char:   1
Error:  ActiveX component can't create object: 'getobject'
Code:   800A01AD
Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Is your task running with restricted privileges? Are you on a 64-bit OS? If so, make sure the WSCRIPT.EXE you're using in your task/bat is the one you want (\System32 for 64-bit or \SysWOW64 for 32-bit).

Comment: Works for me. I suspect something is wrong with the configuration of your scheduled task. What did you configure in the task's security options? The error message suggests that there is no Word process running in the context of the user the task is running as.

Comment: the task is set to run with the highest privileges, under the Admin account. The Word instance is created by a .NET application running under the same account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this similar issue, I bypassed it by utilizing cscript.exe application to activate the vbscript as a console application rather than a windows application. There is a possibility that there is a limitation on the domain or computer which does not allow windows applications to be executed via wscript. As an alternative, try activating the same script via "Cscript.exe" instead.

So the code would be:

```
cscript C:\dev\checkALPS.vbs
```

And the get object method is not activated off of the wscript executable. So you would need to activate it via wscript.

```
dim oWord
Dim wshShell, btn
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

set oWord = Wscript.GetObject(, "Word.Application")

if isobject(oWord) then 
    on error goto 0
    wshShell.Popup "Word is running, making visible", 7, "ALPS Push print", &H0 + &H40
    oWord.visible=true
    wshShell.Popup "MS Word is now visible" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Waiting 30 seconds then hiding it", 30, "ALPS Push print", &H0 + &H30
    oWord.visible=false
else    
    wshShell.Popup "Word is not running" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Quitting", 7, "ALPS Push print", &H0 + &H40
end if
```

Give that a swing and let me know how it works.

Comment: How to make it run without a window?

Comment: @oO. Check out the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info section. Specifically under "Executing scripts locally".