# Run as clicked vbs from Scheduled Tasks - Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have a .vbs file called test.vbs. And this is running test.bat file silently.

In test.bat file,

```
CD.>"C:\folder\empty.srt"
dir /b /s "C:\folder" | findstr /m /i "\.srt$" > C:\old.txt
CD.>C:\new.txt
.
.
echo for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /G:%new% /I /L /B /V %old%') do (@echo %%~nxa >> C:\added.txt)
.
.
CD.>C:\added.txt
del "C:\folder\empty.srt"
```

When I run test.vbs manually .bat file works fine.
But when I run test.vbs from Windows' Scheduled Tasks (command is: C:\test.vbs (tried wscript test.vbs) )

Only creates empty.srt and removes empty.srt. The other commands are not working.
I don't understand why (maybe administrator priviliges (Account is administrator too).

I thought running as administrator would solve the problem. Or is there another way to do this? How can I do that?

edit: Also working when I run this command from CMD --> wscript C:\test.vbs

Also its working fine on Windows 8

Comment: Do you have the checkbox `Run with highest privileges` checked?

Comment: Yes, I tried checked, I tried user group as SYSTEM. Not worked. Runs it but not properly, I think I should fix something in that bat file :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran into this issue a while back, as well as have answered a [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937151/vbscript-and-batch-file-fails-when-run-by-task-scheduler/22077050#22077050) of this issue before.

If it's a 64 bit operating system, then you need to open the script via "C:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe your_vbs_code.vbs" if not, just use "C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe".